# Store token locally in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin cross-platform native project and I have to store the token (get from the server after login) both Android and IOS side. On the Android side I used SharedPreferences which works great, but I can't find a solution for IOS. Now I am using KeyChain, but the result is always wrong.

Here is my code:

The KeyChain class:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using Security;

namespace BloodNotes.iOS
{
    public class KeyChain
    {
        public string ValueForKey(string key)
        {
            var record = ExistingRecordForKey(key);
            SecStatusCode resultCode;
            var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(record, out resultCode);

            if (resultCode == SecStatusCode.Success)
                return NSString.FromData(match.ValueData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }

        public void SetValueForKey(string value, string key)
        {
            var record = ExistingRecordForKey(key);
            if (value == "")
            {
                if (ValueForKey(key) != "")
                    RemoveRecord(record);

                return;
            }

            // if the key already exists, remove it
            if (ValueForKey(key) != "")
                RemoveRecord(record);

            var result = SecKeyChain.Add(CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(key, value));
            if (result != SecStatusCode.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error adding record: " + result));  // I ALWAYS GET THIS EXCEPTION
            }
        }

        private SecRecord CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(string key, string value)
        {
            return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Account = key,
                ValueData = NSData.FromString(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8),
            };
        }

        private SecRecord ExistingRecordForKey(string key)
        {
            return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Account = key,
                Label = key,
            };
        }

        private bool RemoveRecord(SecRecord record)
        {
            var result = SecKeyChain.Remove(record);
            if (result != SecStatusCode.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error removing record: {0}", result));
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And the TokenService:

```
using BloodNotes.ViewModel;
using Foundation;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BloodNotes.iOS.TokenService
{
    class TokenService : Service.ITokenService
    {
        public const string KEY = "token";

        public void SaveToken(string token)
        {
            KeyChain storage = new KeyChain();
            storage.SetValueForKey(token, KEY);

            Debug.WriteLine("RESULT: " + storage.ValueForKey(KEY));
        } 
    }
}
```

Please, give me advise.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. Instead of KeyChain use NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults, so my TokenService looks  like:

```
using Foundation;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BloodNotes.iOS.TokenService
{
    class TokenService : Service.ITokenService
    {
        public const string KEY = "token";

        public void SaveToken(string token)
        {
            var storage = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
            NSString value = new NSString(token);
            NSString key = new NSString(KEY);
            storage.SetValueForKey(value, key);

            Debug.WriteLine("RESULT: " + storage.ValueForKey(key).ToString());
        } 
    }
}
```